# Why can't i define a grid template in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to define a template so that I can use it in my code behind.

```
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="editColumnTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="deleteButton" Content="X"  Command="{Binding Path=ClickMeCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Edit" Width="35" CellTemplate="editColumnTemplate"/>
    </GridView>
```

I'm trying to do this so that in my code behind i can do:

```
GridViewColumn newColumn = new GridViewColumn();
newColumn.CellTemplate = editColumnTemplate;
```

but i get an error in this line :

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Edit" Width="35" CellTemplate="editColumnTemplate"/>
```

> The Type Converter for "Data Template" does not support converting
>   from a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DataTemplate is Resource which is defined for window and hence it has to referred a Resource when you try to use it.

Define it as Static Resouce.

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Edit" 
                Width="35" 
                CellTemplate="{StaticResource editColumnTemplate}"/>
```

Good Explaination here: [XAML Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613(v=vs.110).aspx)